# Hyper-V server 2012 nic teaming setup and virtual switch configuration

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, network-teaming

I have a server with 2 nics. I installed Hyper-v 2012 server (not windows server 2012, no gui) I am trying to set up load balancing.  I have both nics in the same switch currently in trunk mode and no native vlan. I use the `new-netlbfoteam` command to create a team with both nics, I can then `set-netlbfoteamnic "Nic Team" -vlanid 4` so that its available to me with a DHCP or static address but as soon as I try to create a virtual switch it becomes unresponsive. My guess is that is due to it removing the vlan tagging I setup. if I `add-netlbfoteamnic` and set it for vlan 4, then set the IP I can ping it from my management computer but I just get an error.

> `an error occurred while attempting to connect to server "xxxxxx" Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.

Comment: Solution - don't use 2008 RSAT with hyper-v 2012, it works to a point but won't tell you why it failed.

Comment: Probably you should consider do not use hyper-v at all so.